# What does it mean DNS Suffix Search List?

Tags: active-directory, domain, ipconfig

Just for me to understand more, when I run `ipconfig /all` on my work laptop, at the beginning of the information I see 3 parameters: Host Name, Primary DNS Suffix and DNS Suffix Search List.

I know the first one is the hostname of my laptop and I know the second one is the name of the domain that my laptop is bound too.

I do not understand the third one: **DNS Suffix Search List**

Let me give you an example:

Host Name: MyLaptopPC

Primary DNS Suffix: network.ad.companyA.com

**DNS Suffix Search List:**

network.ad.companyA.com

ad.companyA.com

ad.companyB.com

companyB.com

Answer (score 1):

If you query a single label name, Windows appends the DNS suffixes and queries each fully-qualified name in order.

Comment: I can imagine the usage to have list of domains with trust in the forest. Not necessary have to be the case (depends on setting) but it can be one of the use case ;-).